# ASP.net Web Application uploaded to the hostgator through ftp does not allow to view them. It throws 403 error

Tags: asp.net, web-hosting, http-status-code-403

I was able to successfully upload my ASP.net web application to hostgator server through FTP. But I cannot access it by URL. It throws 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.

You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

I checked the permissions. Permissions are given to ALL.

Is there any other setting I need to be checked on... ?

Answer (score 0):

If you receive forbidden error message, it means that you haven't setup your own default page correctly. Please refer to this post https://windowswebhostingreview.com/troubleshoot-403-error-when-publishing-asp-net-core/